# Windows: Search whole computer for a file even if the type is not standard

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, search

To test capabilites of the file search option in Windows Explorer I created a sample file named `sample_code.h` and `sample_code.cpp` on my disc with some text in them so they are not empty.

Now I try to search for those files by clicking on Start -> typing `sample_code` -> selecting `documents` tab -> search in File Explorer.

When I search the Windows Explorer for `sample_code` I don't get anything back. Even though the files are here where I left them.

How am I supposed to search for a file in Windows? What's the correct procedure?

Comment: Suggest _Everything_ from https://www.voidtools.com/ an Open Source filename search tool which will be much more satisfying than search with Explorer.

Comment: In what location were they saved?

Comment: Some may not like my opinion.. but the windows explorer search has sucked since anything post windows-9x and Nt4.  "How am I supposed to search for a file in Windows?".. you use something NOT MADE by Microsoft.  I have been using [this](https://www.funduc.com/search_replace.htm) for years.. but it is a paid app.  @K7AAY suggestion is probably good.  Microsoft search and search indexer suck.  They tried to make it smart and failed (for 20+ years now).  It will find worthless metadata in an excel file but fail to find simple text in a text file and they NEVER fix it.

Comment: @HelpingHand It's nested six levels down in the disc. All folders that are represented in the path were created by me, no default folders were encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am confined to use what comes in the tin, I use [dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)

```
cd \
dir /A:H-D /s sample_code.*
```

The switches:
 **/A** All files
 **/S** All subdirectories
 **:H** Include hidden files
 **-D** exclude directories (i.e., files only)

If I am free to suggest third party tools, use Everything from https://voidtools.com an Open Source filename search tool which will be much more satisfying than search with Explorer.

Comment: The dir solution did not work. As @DualPolarity pointed out the location I have the files saved in is probably not indexed. However, voidtools did excellent job. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the locations you saved "sample_code.h" and "sample_code.cpp" are not indexed by Windows, they may not appear in searches.

[Search indexing in Windows 10: FAQ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4098843/windows-10-search-indexing-faq)